# Xcode 4.4 + OSX 10.5 as Development target = Clang LLVM 1.0 error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-leopard

Try this on the new Xcode 4.4: create a new project, a Cocoa application, and set the Development Target to OSX 10.5.
If you run it, you'll get this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Can someone explain this? I want to support Leopard too in my projects but I get this error if I try to execute them.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your project does not use ARC. ARC is not supported on Leopard.

(It is supported on Snow Leopard, sans weak references)

The actual error, btw, is probably before the line you copy/pasted in your question.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem... but... now i have to fix every memory allocation errors! ARC worked without problems compiling with Xcode 4.3, even on Leopard

Comment: I doubt ARC worked on Leopard. Did you actually try to run an app built with ARC on Leopard?

Comment: Yes, it worked with no problems... it was compiling on Xcode 4.3 and running on every OSX versions. That same project now gave me that problem at compile time on Xcode 4.4